# How to export/push my local database in MongoDB atlas

Tags: python, database, mongodb, database-connection

I've got a database in my local machine and I've created a cluster in MongoDB atlas and also connect it. I want to export/push my DB to the cluster.I created the dump of my database using this command **mongodump --db all_product --collection product**

```
My database:
    > show dbs
    admin        0.000GB
    all_product  0.000GB
    config       0.000GB
    local        0.000GB
    > use all_product
    switched to db all_product
    > show collections
    product
    > db.product.count()
    522
```

I tried the binary export mongorestore using this command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mongorestore --host allProducts-shard-0/allproducts-shard-00-00-k6ufl.mongodb.net:27017,allproducts-shard-00-01-k6ufl.mongodb.net:27017,allproducts-shard-00-02-k6ufl.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username shakib --password <testpass> --authenticationDatabase admin
```

but I'm getting this error - **The system cannot find the file specified**

How to set the file path or what should I do. My mongo DB files are stored in **C:\data\db**

Comment: Have you tried specifying the database file path ?
for a collection at least, I use the cmd :
`mongorestore -h "your_host" -d "your db" -c "your-collection" -u <user> -p <password> collection.bson`
so it should be similar

Comment: Can you try adding `--file \c\data\db` or do `cd C:data\db` and then do your command.

Comment: I tried both of them but I'm getting the same error @ViharManchala

Comment: That's not working mate @lalam

Comment: The mongodump command that you used should create a dump folder in the directory. Can you see that?

Comment: If yes, then you have to run the mongorestore from that directory

Comment: I found the dump folder & I tried running that command from that directory but the same error is coming.I also tried the other command using the file extension but no luck @ViharManchala

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the directory using --dir explicitly.
Refer the code below

```
mongorestore --ssl --host <host> --authenticationDatabase admin --dir="<dumpDirectory>" -u <adminUserName> --password <password>

<host>: get from mongo atlas dashboard (click on the cluster name) ex: cluster0-shard-00-00-cbei2.mongodb.net:27017 
<dumpDirectory>: The folder where database is dumped using mongodump
<adminUserName>: admin User for that database
<password>: admin associated password
```